# Mounted SD card not working

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, huawei

I recently mounted an SD card to my phone. But when I tried to download an application from the play store, a message popped up saying my phone didn't have any storage on it, saying my internal storage was low, but my SD card had 28.2 GB on it left, which my phone had recognized. Yet applications weren't being installed using the SD card, whilst any photos taken are stored using the SD card.

Any advice of what to do or how to fix this problem?

Comment: Apps must explicitly support to be installed on SD card – maybe those you've chosen don't. Also, can you check whether your devices supports [App2SD](/tags/app2sd/info) at all? AFAIK Huawei still supports this feature (while most manufacturers don't but rather favor [adoptable storage](/tags/adoptable-storage/info)). You can check this in *Settings › Apps*, see if there's an option to move apps to SD or to show which apps are installed on the card.

Answer (score 0):

APPS CANNOT BE PLACED ON SD CARD. It's possible with app like link2sd (need root) or adopting sd card (android 6+ feature, see [adoptable storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)).

Some phones including Huawei have 'Move to SD' option but this option move files in internal SD (if `/data` and `/sdcard` are separated partitions) or move very small amount of data. For details, also take look at [app2sd wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info) and [link2sd wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/link2sd/info).